# Put DrawingGroup on a Canvas?

Tags: wpf, drawing, canvas

I have a DrawingGroup and I want to put it on a Canvas, but because DrawingGroup is no UIElement, this is not possible. Whats the best way to do this? And from which class could I derive, so that I could do something like

```
canvas1.Children.Add(new myDrawingGroup());
```

(Meaning I want to add my DrawingGroup as one element on the canvas, instead of several single Drawings / Geometries. I also need hit testing and databinding support.)

Thank you very much for any hint!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For the records: I ended up using DrawingVisuals.